# TypeORM Relationship

Tags: typescript, sqlite, relationship, typeorm

I am trying to avoid having to do a second query to save a row with a relationship.  A user can create several events.  Any user is going to go through auth and I will have access to the userID. I don't fully understand relationships.  It seems like I should be able to make the relationship on a type number linked to the User ID, instead of the entire User object.

The Entity is

```
import {
  Entity,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  Column,
  JoinColumn,
  ManyToOne,
} from 'typeorm';
import { User } from './User';

@Entity()
export class Event {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  eventName: string;


  @ManyToOne(() => User)
  @JoinColumn()
  createdBy: User;
}

export default Event;
```

The Controller

```
const userRepository = AppDB.getRepository(User);
const EventRepository = AppDB.getRepository(Event);

export async function addEvent(userID: number, eventObject: EventObject) {
  const u = await userRepository.findOneByOrFail({ id: userID }); //Trying to Remove <---
  const e = new Event();
  Object.assign(e, eventObject);
  e.eventStart = new Date(eventObject.eventStart);
  e.eventEnd = new Date(eventObject.eventEnd);
  e.createdBy = u; //e.createBy = userID. <----
  await EventRepository.save(e);
  return e;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I can not test this but the way I did this: You could add a name for the `JoinColumn` and add a column with this exact name. This way you don't need to get the entity and is sufficient to just set the id.

```
@ManyToOne(() => User)
  @JoinColumn({name: 'createdById')
  createdBy: User;

  @Column()
  createdById: number; // use the type of the User's entity primary key
```

```
const EventRepository = AppDB.getRepository(Event);

export async function addEvent(userID: number, eventObject: EventObject) {
  const e = new Event();
  Object.assign(e, eventObject);
  e.eventStart = new Date(eventObject.eventStart);
  e.eventEnd = new Date(eventObject.eventEnd);
  e.createdById = userID;
  await EventRepository.save(e);
  return e;
}
```